# Check series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to check the following series for convergence:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\ln(n^2 + 1) - 2\ln(n)) $

Basic transformations: $ x_n = \ln(n^2 + 1) - 2\ln(n) = \ln(1 + 1/n^2) $

Given logarithm definition we have:
$$
e^\left(x_n\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} = ((1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^\left(n^2\right))^\frac{1}{n^2}
$$

From here I'm not sure what to do. The intuition is that we get the limit of previous:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ((1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^\left(n^2\right))^\frac{1}{n^2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^\left(x_n\right)$$

And from this $x_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{n^2} $ so series behaves like $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $ (convergent).

That's just intuition and I have no idea how to prove that series converges. I would be grateful for any tips.

*This is a homework assignment.*

Comment: You can skip the potentiation: it is sufficient to observe that $\ln (1+a) = O(a)$ for small $|a|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT** Use Limit Comparison Test with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^2}$

Comment: Since (1+1/n^2)^n^2 < e (limit from bottom) then 1/n^2 > x_n and Limit Comparison Test proves convergence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First we claim that $\ln(1+u)\leq u$ for $u\geq 0$. Let $\varphi(u)=u-\ln(1+u)$ for $u\geq 0$, then by Mean Value Theorem we have $\varphi(u)=\varphi(u)-\varphi(0)=\varphi'(\xi_{u})u=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{1+\xi_{u}}\right)u\geq 0$ for some $\xi_{u}\in[0,u]$.

Now we make use such inequality, so $\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\leq\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$, summing up we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Please note that 
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \left (\log x_n\right)=\log\left (\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}  x_n\right)$$

And  then you will be able to show that  $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}  x_n = 1$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\ln(n^2+1)-2\ln(n)=\ln(\frac{n^2+1}{n^2})$$

$$=\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})\sim \frac{1}{n^2}\;(n\to +\infty).$$

the general terms are equivalent and positives, both series are convergent.